# List workspaces of a user on a specific machine in Perforce

Tags: list, perforce, workspace

How can I get all Perfoce workspaces of a  specific user on a **specific** machine?

This command let me all workspaces of a  specific user on **all machines**:

```
P4 clients -u username
```

Comment: Often there's no single command that gives you exactly what you want, but a simple script that combines several commands does the trick. What's your preferred scripting language for building tools like these? That will make it easier for people to help you. Also, what have you tried so far, and where did you run into trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cmd one-liner that does more or less the same thing as pitseeker's:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %x in ('p4 clients -u username') do @(echo %x & p4 client -o %x | findstr /r /c:"^Host:")
```

A somewhat more robust batch file that seems to fit what you're looking for is:

```
@echo off
set USER=%1
set HOST=%2
REM Don't forget to double your for-loop percents in batch files,
REM unlike the one-liner above...
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('p4 clients -u %USER%') do call :CheckClient %%x
goto :EOF

:CheckClient
p4 client -o %1 | findstr /r /c:"^Host:" | findstr /i /r /c:"%HOST%$">nul && echo %1
goto :EOF
```

Save that and run it with the username as the first parameter and the desired host name as the second.  That is, something like `showclient elady elady_pc`

Comment: Thanks! that's what I looked for. (It neatly works due to the fact that workspace name with spaces is not allowed)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but it's easy and perhaps sufficient:

```
p4 clients -u username | cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 p4 client -o  |egrep -e '^Client|^Host'
```

This lists all your clients and their host-restrictions (if any).
In the resulting list you can find the specific machines very easily.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention before, I'm working on Windows, so I can't use 'cut' or 'egrep' commands